# Forcing text to span N lines

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div that has a variable width (responsive). The text content is dynamically created by the user so the line length can differ due to the content. Is there a way to have the text inside wrap to exactly 3 lines stacked on-top of each other? Ideally without using javascript or php (although if bootstrap is bundled with a js solution i'm not strongly opposed)

So

```
<div>Here is some example text that regardless of the div width is always three lines</div>
```

Would render as

```
Here is some example text that 
regardless of the div width
is always three lines
```

regardless if the div spans the entire width of the page or a just a few rems.

```
And
another
example
```

I do not want to truncate the text or add elipses. If the text overflows from the div but stays stacked in three lines that is acceptable. If it makes a difference I'm using bootstrap 4 beta.

Comment: just set the height of the div to 3x your line-height and add overflow hidden - https://jsfiddle.net/uo30mwev/

Comment: I don't think you can do this with CSS unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

If you can set a class on the DIVs like this:

```
<div class="UserDynamic">Here is some example text that regardless of the div width is always three lines</div>
```

then add to CSS:

```
div.UserDynamic{height:3em}
```

Or if you can't set the DIVs for the user-generated bit, then, encase the entire user area in a single div like this:

```
<div class="UserDynamics"><!--user content appears in this div-->
    <div>Here is some example text that regardless of the div width is always three lines</div>

    <div>Here is more example text that regardless of the div width is always three lines</div>
</div>
```

And in CSS:

```
div.UserDynamics div{height:3em}
```

Comment: The div seems to expand with the text keeping everything on the one line

Comment: Add "width:6em" to the CSS. This will make it wrap MOST words, although longer words may cause horizontal scrollbars to appear, and, you may end up with 2 or more shorter words on the same line. Whether this is acceptable depends on your design use-cases!